# jquery ajax post sends me to action page and wont show result data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have the following script for making Ajax/Jquery post request.
The script works (I get correct response on back-end).
But I cant seem to make any alerts, so I think there is some problem with the success function. 
Do you guys see any obvious mistakes?
The browser gets the correct responses (Inspect webpage in chrome).

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var frm = $('#registerform');
                frm.submit(function(x) {
                    x.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/register',
                        data: frm.serialize(),
                        crossDomain: true,
                        success: function(data){
                            if(data == 200){
                                alert("successfully registered");
                                $('#alert').append("successfully registered");
                            }
                            if (data == 400){
                                alert("email or password empty");
                            }
                            if(data == 403){
                                alert("passwords do not match");
                            }
                        }
                    });

                });
            });
      </script>
```

Comment: Can you console.log data and check the resulted value? The if probably returns false

Comment: Could you try moving `x.preventDefault()` to after the ajax call?  That's how the example is in the jQuery documentation.

Comment: Okey, when playing with console.log i see that my response is not 200.. it's "OK". The message from the http status code 200 which is the response from the backend... So if i change if(data =="OK") it works....

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare your data that you are getting back from your request with HTTP status codes. So, what you need do is put in some additional parameters in your success function. Here is a nice Fiddle that I seen on another stackoverflow question that might help you out. http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/55HQq/3/.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/echo/xml/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        //Set an empty response to see the error
        xml: "<response></response>"   
    },
    dataType:"text xml",
    success: function(xml, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(arguments);
        console.log(xhr.status);
    }
});
```

The xhr.status is what you will need to compare against instead of your data.

Comment: Ye I compared them with status codes, thought that I got back a status code and not the status message. Fixed it, you can see my own answer. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When playing with console.log i found out that sending res.sendStatus(200) from the backend results in the client (browser) getting the response "OK". So when changing to res.json on the server it works...